# Corresponding MySQL datatype to Java Date()

Tags: java, mysql, date, types

I am writing a RESTful web service that needs to save a Java Date() value to MySQL database, however, I am not sure what's the datatype in MySQL that can hold Java Date(), or should I convert the java Date() object to String type before saving into MySQL?

Comment: You can use `Date` or `DateTime` field type.

Comment: Do you want to store the Date or the Date and Time?

Comment: I want to store date and time (yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the MySQL types DATE, DATETIME, or TIMESTAMP. Do something like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
...
Date date = ...;
query.bindParameter("date",sdf.format(date))
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am not sure what's the datatype in MySQL that can hold Java Date(),
>   or should I convert the java Date() object to String type before
>   saving into MySQL?

You can simply Use `java.sql` package

```
preparedStatement.setDate(1,new Date(calendar.getTime()));
```

OR

```
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(2,new Timestamp(calendar.getTime()));
```